# Receber dados de uma Tabela numa pagina php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Saudações!!
Estou a tentar fazer algo que a essas alturas náo sei se é possivel. Tenho uma tabela numa pagina html, que peguei a mesma e transformei em um array de objetos que a apartir do Ajax envio o mesmo array para uma outra pagina php que depois irei visualiza-lá em forma de tabela.

```
    //Envia para o php
    function mandar_tabela() {



    var indices = [];

    //Pega os indices
    $('#tabela-preços thead tr th').each(function() {
        indices.push($(this).text());
    });

    var arrayItens = [];

    //Pecorre todos os produtos
    $('#tabela-preços tbody tr').each(function(index) {

        var obj = {};

        //Controle o objeto
        $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
            obj[indices[index]] = $(this).text();
        });

        //Adiciona no arrray de objetos
        arrayItens.push(obj);

    });

    //Mostra dados pegos no console
    console.log(arrayItens);

    //Envia para o php
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "imprimirfatura1.php",
        data: arrayItens,
        success: function() {
            alert('Deu tudo certo');
        },
    });
}
```

Contudo, na hora de receber na pagina php não consigo, nem mesmo visualizar o array de objetos mandado. Quando abro a pagina **imprimirtabela.php** não encontro absolutamente nada. tentei usar o metodo POST mas nao consegui, seis o pedaço de código da página **imprimirtabela.php** seguinte:

```
<?php 
 $array[] = $_POST['arrayItem'];
$pagina="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
[...]
```

Como faço para receber esse array de objetos com o ajax, e visualizar na pagina **imprimirtabela.php**

Comment: se fizer um `$.ajax` não vai sair da página atual, deveria fazer um *submit*  para a outra página, e por o array por exemplo num campo *input type hidden* para assim poder fazer request na outra página

Comment: Ricardo Pontual, não percebi. Acabo de atualizar a pergunta, colocando toda função do javascript

Comment: uma request ajax retorna para a mesma página, pelo que percebi quer enviar os dados para outra página e a partir da outra página criar a table é isso?

Comment: Isso Mesmo Ricardo, Quero enviar os dados para outra página.

Comment: pois então a forma de fazer isso é colocar tudo numa tag form, por exemplo `<form action='imprimirtabela.php'>...aqui vão todos os campos, </form>` e por o resultado do array num campo dentro da tag form. Se ficar com dúvidas avise

Comment: Então, com isso, eu teria que colocar minha tabela dentro de um form, depois converter ele em array, certo?

Comment: eu coloquei numa resposta para ficar mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Para explicar melhor, vou colocar um exemplo:

**HTML**:

```
<form id="formImprimir" action='imprimirtabela.php'>

   ... aqui tudo que precisa ser enviado

   ... e esse input que vai conter o array de objetos
   <input type="hidden" id="array-itens" name="array-itens" />
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
... aqui monta o objeto arrayItens
// Serializa o objeto
var arrayItensSerializado = JSON.stringify(arrayItens);
// Seta o campo input com o valor
document.getElementById("array-itens").value = arrayItensSerializado;
// Faz submit do form
document.getElementById("formImprimir").submit();
// Não precisa do ajax.
```

**PHP (imprimirtabela.php):**

```
// Pega o valor de "array-itens"
$json = $_POST['array-itens'];
// Converte para objeto
$itens = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem a pergunta mas, caso você queira inserir alguns dados em uma tabela por chamada AJAX usando jQuery, seria mais ou menos isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  EnviaDataTable();
})

function EnviaDataTable() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "imprimirfatura1.php",
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: arrayItens,
    success: function(dados) {
      var tabela = $("#table").DataTable();
      tabela.clear().draw();

      $.each(dados, function(index, value) {
        tabela.row.add([
          value.column1,
          value.column2,
          value.column3,
          value.column4
          //...
        ]).draw();
      })

      tabela.columns.adjust().draw();

    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" name="table" width="100%">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```